# Registered client android device for push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

how to registered client's android device for the push notification without be connected to the machine.

I know how to registered device for push notification while connect it to the machine.

But how we can generate device registration id for the client via GCM without connected physically with the machine

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> how to registered client's android device for the push notification
>   without be connected to the machine.

You have to register your Reg. ID of your Device to Enable GCM Push Notification Service for your app. and to register it you will have to call a WS from your Device to register it to your Server.

> But how we can generate device registration id for the client via GCM
>   without connected physically connect with the machine

AFAIK this is not Possible. As your Reg ID will be change in Various Scenarios(phone restart etc) you will then have to Update your regId to your Server. and for this you will need to connect your Mobile to Server.

Comment: Is there any solution to get client's registration Process with GCM without connecting device physically with machine

Comment: I want to insert registration process code in the startup page to get registration code of the client device. I this possible without connect to machine

Comment: are you trying to send regId to server without internet connection?

Comment: No - I just want to put code in my startup page to registered the client device. I have code for registration of the device while connecting them physically with machine.

Comment: Looking for some WC that carried out registration process for my client's device without physically connected to machine